# incluir librerias externas en qtcreator

Tags: c, qt-creator

Necesito incluir librerias externas a una aplicacion que tengo en Qt Creator. En mi caso necesito incluir la libreria `xmpp` pero no se como ya que soy nuevo en este ide y no tengo mucha idea. Lei un tutorial por internet pero no lo consegui: https://daganu.wordpress.com/2012/12/

¿Cómo instalo librerias externas en este IDE?

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Esta es la libreria que quiero agregar:
[image: libreria xmpp]

Answer (score 2):

Las librerías de [c](/questions/tagged/c) o [c++](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b) no se "*instalan*". Si tienes el código fuente de la librería (que parece ser tu caso) tan sólo debes hacer que las cabeceras necesarias (los archivos `.h` o `.hpp`) sean visibles desde el archivo en que se solicita su acceso, esto se puede hacer de dos maneras:

#### Ruta absoluta

Suponiendo que tienes el archivo `xmpp.h` en `C:/mis_proyectos/librerias/xmpp/src` puedes escribir en el código:

```
#include "C:/mis_proyectos/librerias/xmpp/src/xmpp.h"
```

Pero eso es tedioso además de propenso a errores (si cambias la ruta deberás cambiar el código).

#### Ruta relativa

Cualquier IDE (Qt Creator incluido) ofrece la posibilidad de configurar unas rutas desde las cuales se buscan las cabeceras a incluir, Qt usa el [sistema QMake](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Qmake), el archivo de QMake puedes editarlo a mano para añadir una línea como esta:

```
INCLUDEPATH += C:/mis_proyectos/librerias/xmpp/src/
```

Esa línea te permitirá escribir en el código:

```
#include "xmpp.h"
```

Y el IDE buscará en primer lugar en las ruta en que el archivo a compilar se encuentre y seguidamente en todas las rutas indicadas en `INCLUDEPATH` (es ligeramente más complejo pero esto es una explicación simplificada)

---

Si editar el archivo de QMake a mano te resulta incómodo, puedes usar [la interfaz](http://doc.qt.io/qtcreator/creator-project-qmake-libraries.html) de añadir librerías haciendo click secundario sobre el panel **Projects**, seleccionando **Add Library** y siguiendo las instrucciones.